# Android TextWatcher behavior

Tags: android

Although code is far from being complete, for the begining I tried to detect via TextWatcher 
when character is pressed in EditText that doesn't belong to hex values and not to permit it
to be displayed, but to inform user of error entry. 
The excerpt from code follows, where arrayOfChars consists of 16 permitted hex chars and edt2 
is EditText var. What I tried is to enter following chars: "aeyd", so it is aim to inform of 
"y" as an error and not to display it.

```
     edt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){         
        private boolean errorDetected= false;
        private int oldbefore;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
            String st;
            if (errorDetected){ //set in code bellow
                errorDetected= false;
                return;
            }               
            st= s.toString();
            if (before > 0){
               if (before<= s.length()){st= s.subSequence(before, s.length()).toString();}  
            }  
            boolean velid= true;
            for (char c: st.toCharArray()){
                if (new String(arrayOfChars).indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(c))==-1){ 
                   edt2.setError("Wrong char - " + c);
                   errorDetected= true; 
                   oldbefore= before; 
                   velid= false;  
                   break;
                }
            }                               
            if (velid) {edt2.setError(null);}               
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (errorDetected){s.delete(oldbefore, s.length());}
        }
    });
```

When "y" is entered everything behave as expected- only "ae" displayed and error info also.
However when "d" is entered and breakpoint settled at the beginning of onTextChanged, I see 
"s" parameter to be "aeyd"- so "y" is still preserved somehow. 
Any help where I go wrong ?

Comment: Dont use TextWatcher for this,  see TextView.setFilters() method

Comment: Thank you- didn't know, so I'll try. Then it seems that TextWatcher is more appropriate for changing entered text on fly ?

Comment: it is more for "watching" the changes while filter is more for "filtering"